# How to solve a unable to find valid certification path to requested target error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, get-request

I am getting this error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    `at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:130)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:371)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:309)`
```

How should I solve this error in eclipse

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code

Comment: Please show the code as text and tell the exact Java version with which you run your code. @MikeSzyndel

Comment: Does running your code with a newer Java version work?

Comment: This sometimes happens behind a corporate firewall, which might require a specific root certificate to be installed in the cacerts truststore of your JDK.